# Selecting all text under div tag with cheerio

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, cheerio

```
<div id="ftext">
    A
    <br><br>
    B
    <br><br>
    C
    <br><br>
    <div style="float:right;">
     D
    </div>
    <div class='clear'></div>
</div>
```

I want to select and store the "A B C" under #ftext into a variable as a string and store "D" in another variable. Using cheerio. Thanks!

Comment: What did you tried ?

Comment: I'm new to nodejs and cheerio so im not sure if im doing this correctly, but i've tried:

$("#ftext").text()

and map()

Answer (score 0):

A B and C are separate nodes, so maybe join them:

```
let abc = $("#ftext")[0].children.map(e => e.nodeValue).join('')
```

For D maybe select the div with a style attribute like so:

```
let d = $("#ftext div[style]").text()
```

Comment: both abc and d doesn't work, console produce empty line output when I try to print them

Comment: Then either the html isn't what you think or you're not loading it properly.